# Batch insert to database with skipping duplicates found in database

Tags: sql, spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-data

I'd like to save to the database a list of objects using Spring. In my controller I receive a list of strings, say these are cities. I filter out duplicated and have a unique `Set` of cities. How do I insert that set the database when I have a unique constraint on the city column?
I see three options here:

1. Before any insert I check whether there is already such a record, if there is none, I persist the domain object.
2. I try to persist the object domain object without checking whether it exists in the database or not. When I encounter an SQL Exception, I try to save another domain object.
3. I retrieve all the objects from the database (the list of records may definitely be larger than 100 thousand), then I create a set of unique (absent in database) domain objects and then save these to the database.

What would be the option to go? Is there (hopefully) a better option?

Comment: can you create a global temporary table or have access to an empty table that you can stage the data in?  Always best to do the processing on the database side for operations like this

Comment: Yes, I can make this happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a [global temporary table](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables) owned by the oracle user that does the inserts with the same structure as the destination table. The following pseudo code shoud give you an idea. The least fuss is have it created with ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS but sometimes it is easier to use ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS and start off every session with

```
DELETE FROM <your global temporary table>;
```

Then insert all your data from Spring into this table.  I will assume that there are no duplicate ID's or duplicate cities with the same ID in the destination table.

```
INSERT INTO <your destination table> SELECT city_id, city_name, third_field
FROM <your global temporary table> 
WHERE <your global temporary table>.city_name
NOT IN (SELECT <your destination table>.city_name
FROM <your destination table>);
```

If you have duplicate city names with different ID you can just add another NOT IN clause.